# Typesetting the arc symbol over three letters

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How do I put the arc symbol over three letters to indicate that the three letters together represent an angle?  For example, the display from the following code gives five points - `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` on a circle.  I want to say something like "the ratio \arc{ABC} to \arc{AEC} is 2 to 3."

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);

\draw (234:1) -- (162:1) -- (90:1) -- (18:1) -- (-54:1) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=234+180] at (234:1) {$A$};
\node[anchor=162+180] at (162:1) {$B$};
\node[anchor=90+180] at (90:1) {$C$};
\node[anchor=18+180] at (18:1) {$D$};
\node[anchor=-54+180] at (-54:1) {$E$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.2in
\noindent In the preceding figure, a regular pentagon is inscribed in a circle. What is the ratio of the length of arc $\mathit{{ABC}}$ to the length of arc ${\mathit{AEC}}$?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216008/adjusting-symbols-above-letter-in-mathmode

Comment: Again, why the [tag:tex-core] tag? Have you seen [A better notation to denote arcs for an American high school textbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96680)?

Comment: As Paul says, this is a possible duplicate of [A better notation to denote arcs for an American high school textbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96680/a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook). Another approach is given in [adjusting symbols above letter in mathmode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216008/adjusting-symbols-above-letter-in-mathmode).